# NodeJS tell open(html) to go first/tell other code to go last

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to determine if nodeJS is a viable solution for a work project at my internship. TLDR: I need to have my basicNode.js file wait until the open('./basic.html') has actually fully opened up the browser and loaded content before it calls any other code, either from basicNode.js itself or from change.js.

End goal/purpose of basicNode.js should be to open the html, and once it's loaded, call the changeThis() function from change.js to alter the html to show "Hello" instead of "Welcome to JavaScript".
I've tried mixing up the order of things or having some console.logs output current time etc before calling the change functions but I just can't seem to get open('./basic.html') to fully complete before any attempt is made to change html elements

1. basic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  
</head>  
<body>
<p>Date/Time: <span id="datetime"></span></p>
  
<p id="here">Welcome to JavaScript</p>  
<form>  
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="changeThis()"/>  
</form>  
</body> 
<script>
var dt = new Date();
    document.getElementById("datetime").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleString();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="change.js"></script> 
<!--
<script>waitForElementToDisplay("#here",function(){alert("Hi");},1000,9000);</script> 
--> 
</html>
```

2. change.js

```
function changeThis() {
    document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = "Hello";
}

function waitForElementToDisplay(selector, callback, checkFrequencyInMs, timeoutInMs) {
  var startTimeInMs = Date.now();
  (function loopSearch() {
    if (document.querySelector(selector) != null) {
      callback();
      return;
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(function () {
        if (timeoutInMs && Date.now() - startTimeInMs > timeoutInMs)
          return;
        loopSearch();
      }, checkFrequencyInMs);
    }
  })();
}

function sendAlert() {
    alert("Hi");
}

module.exports={sendAlert};
module.exports={changeThis};
module.exports={waitForElementToDisplay};
```

3. basicNode.js

```
const open = require('open');
var { change }  = require('./change')
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.document = new JSDOM('./basic.html').window.document;

open('./basic.html');

change.waitForElementToDisplay("#here",change.sendAlert(),1000,9000);
change.changeThis();
```

Comment: If you're asking why it appears that open isn't "going first," `open('./basic.html')` *is* going first, it's just an asynchronous operation and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This is sort of an advanced topic for someone who is new to JS and Node, but if you want to run the change script after you've definitely opened the file, you'll need to await the promise. You can read all about this in the link to MDN above.

Comment: Brendan, you should post that as the answer so you can get credit!

Comment: @BrendanBond I did notice that concept when I nested the open() inside a console.log(), it output Promise {<pending>}, in theory would a possible solution be to implement a check for when the promise has been fulfilled, at which point I could call the change functions?

Comment: Also, instead of await, you could instead use Promise.then, e g. `open('./basic.html').then(() => { change.waitForElementToDisplay("#here",change.sendAlert(),1000,9000); change.changeThis(); })` which returns a new Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why it appears that open isn't "going first," open('./basic.html') is going first, it's just an asynchronous operation and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). This is sort of an advanced topic for someone who is new to JS and Node, but if you want to run the change script after you've definitely opened the file, you'll need to await the promise. You can read all about this in the link to MDN above, and there is a ton of material online about this topic.

```
const open = require('open');
var { change }  = require('./change')
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.document = new JSDOM('./basic.html').window.document;

const main = async () => {
  await open('./basic.html');
  change.waitForElementToDisplay("#here",change.sendAlert(),1000,9000);
  change.changeThis();
}

main();
```

Note that I've wrapped the code in an async function because, for the moment, you can't use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) syntax in the global scope. Alternatively, you could do as @JSmart523 indicated:

```
const open = require('open');
var { change }  = require('./change')
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
global.document = new JSDOM('./basic.html').window.document;


open('./basic.html').then(() => {
  change.waitForElementToDisplay("#here",change.sendAlert(),1000,9000);
  change.changeThis();
});
```

Comment: Thank you @BrendanBond, I think this brings me one step closer; does that code work for you by chance? To change "Welcome to JavaScript" to "Hello"?
This may be a separate issue but as that code stands I get a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'waitForElementToDisplay'), and same for 'changeThis' if I comment out the waitFor function

Comment: No, I didn't run this code. This is definitely a separate issue, check that you're exporting functions from change.js properly (you're not) and that you're importing the module correctly in basicNode.js (also looks incorrect to me). Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok thanks so much! definitely helps to know where to look, I'll be back at it next tuesday getting this to work, any tips on where to look or examples for how I should properly export/import the functions?

Comment: [This series of tutorials](https://nodejs.dev/learn) is a really excellent place to start and should give you the fundamentals you'll need to tackle more complex issues. Have fun and good luck!